# Unit testing for URLSessionDelegate method - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, urlsession, urlauthenticationchallenges

I have a custom delegate class called **`CertificatePinningDelegate`** which conforms to **`URLSessionDelegate`**. I'm using the delegate method

```
urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)
```

to authenticate with the server. Now I want to write a unit test for this.

I've been trying to manually call the delegate method to pass a custom **`URLAuthenticationChallenge`** object, which seems impossible. Does anyone know any alternative/better option for this?